# Limits and transformation rules

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

I can calculate this limit:

```
Limit[(c^(1 - g) - 1)/(1 - g), g -> 1]
```

and obtain the correct value:

> ```
> Log[c]
> ```

but if I try to use a transformation rule (e.g. to plot that function for different values of g), I get an Indeterminate result:

```
Limit[(c^(1 - g) - 1)/(1 - g), g -> d] /. d -> 1
```

> ```
> Indeterminate
> ```

I would assume that the transformation rule applies BEFORE the limit is calculated, but apparently that's not the case; and, on the other hand, I don't know how to force Mathematica to apply the rule before the limit is calculated.

Thanks,

pierpa

Answer (score 6):

```
Unevaluated[Limit[(c^(1 - g) - 1)/(1 - g), g -> d]] /. d -> 1
Hold[Limit[(c^(1 - g) - 1)/(1 - g), g -> d]] /. d -> 1 // ReleaseHold
With[{d = 1}, Limit[(c^(1 - g) - 1)/(1 - g), g -> d]]
Limit[(c^(1 - g) - 1)/(1 - g), g -> #] &@1
Block[{Limit}, SetAttributes[Limit, HoldAll]; Limit[(c^(1 - g) - 1)/(1 - g), g -> d] /. d -> 1]
foo[(c^(1 - g) - 1)/(1 - g), g -> d] /. d -> 1 /. foo -> Limit
```

all give

```
(* Log[c] *)
```

In version 10, you can also use

```
Activate[Inactive[Limit[(c^(1 - g) - 1)/(1 - g), g ->d]] /. d->1]
Activate[Inactive[Limit][(c^(1 - g) - 1)/(1 - g), g ->d] /. d->1] (* thanks: @ybeltukov *)
Activate[Inactivate[Limit[(c^(1 - g) - 1)/(1 - g), g ->d]] /. d->1] (* thanks: @ybeltukov *)
```

Comment: A nice comprehensive list :-) For new functionality the proper usage is `Inactivate[Limit[...]]` or `Inactive[Limit][...]`.

Comment: Thank you @ybeltukov.  All three variants seem work in the Wolfram Cloud platform.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot